# Spotipy request speed in while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, spotify, spotipy

```
count = 0
while True:
        if count > 20:
                count = 0
                current_track = spotify.current_user_playing_track()
                if current_track is None:
                        display_string = ""
                else:
                        display_string = current_track['item']['name']+" - "+current_track['item']['artists'][0]['name']+" | "
                if display_string != previous_track:
                        sphd.clear()
                        sphd.write_string(display_string,brightness=0.1)
                        previous_track = display_string[:]
        time.sleep(0.05)
        sphd.show()
        sphd.scroll(1)
        count += 1
```

The code above is run on a Pi Zero to get the currently playing track every second and display it on a scrollphathd display. The problem is that the process of getting the track causes the display to freeze for about 0.25s. Is there any way of running the loop to get the track separately to refreshing the display's scrolling or any way to speed up getting the track? Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the reason of that freeze is the low performance that the Raspberry Pi Zero has.

Comment: I understand that. Thank you for the reply. I'm just wondering if there is any way to make my code more efficient. There may be something I'm doing unnecessarily that is causing more processing time to be added.